# how to enable tool bar in IE9 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using IE 9 . I need to enable tool bar in IE 9 using JavaScript `toolbar=yes` while opening a new window.

```
window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefID=' + refID, '_self', 'toolbar=yes', false);
```

It works in IE7.

it shows tool bar with out left and right arrows. how to get arrows?

Application developed in vs2010.

Comment: What does your whole `window.open` line look like?

Comment: window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefID=' + refID, '_self', 'toolbar=yes', false);

Comment: i used the above code. it works fine in ie7. not in ie9. idont know why?

Comment: it shows tool bar with out left and right arrows. How to enable it or get

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Internet Explorer Related doubts Here:
Link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/?filter=answered

If you need Support for your Issue use this:
Link: https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?st=1&as=1&as=1&tzone=-330&gprid=807&timestmp=634607158808834724&ps=1&acty=ProductList&ctl=productlist&wf=PID&trl=PID%7eProductList&c=SMC&ln=en-us&prid=14066&gsaid=649481

Hope this may Helpful.....